# Remove @Override annotation errors

Tags: android, overriding, java

I've got a question...
On Eclipse, when I want to load an Android library from the internet, I've got a lot of errors on @Override annotation.

I'am using the JDK 1.7...

Thanks for your help !

Comment: what are the errors? are they just warnings?

Comment: Can you please show the code in which you get the errors, and indicate which annotations are erroneous?

Comment: Please post an actual code of a class whose method  you get the error on?

Comment: It occurs when you use 1.5 compilation and put @Override on methods implemented from an interface.

Comment: Ok, thank you. When I set 1.7 compilation, I've got this error :Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.7' instead. Please use Android Tools > Fix Project Properties. All downloaded library make this error...

Comment: Then do what the error messages tell you and dont use 1.7... Use 1.5 or 1.6.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Android requires](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) that you compile the project using JDK 1.6.  You may get annotation errors if you try to use another version of Java.

To make sure you're using JDK 1.6:

- Right-click on project in Eclipse, go to "Properties".
- Click on "Java Compiler" in the left column.

Here's where you need to make sure that you're **not** using Java version 1.5 OR version 1.7 to compile the project.  You'll need to use JDK 1.6 (see [Android requirements](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)).

- If Eclipse is using 1.6, then uncheck the "Enable project specific settings" on the "Java Compiler" page.

Eclipse should then recognize the @Override annotations when using JDK 1.6.

Answer (score 4):

Android requires Java 1.5 or 1.6.

I would use 1.6 as that won't give you errors when you override an interface method.